# Selection of "DYNAMIC" dropdownlist items from a Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, tablecell

//Code BehindFile

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
             while (reader.Read())
         {

            DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
             string[] s = { "Present", "Absent1", "Absent2", "Absent3" };
             for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
             {
                 ddl.Items.Add(s[i]);
             }
             ddl.ID = "ddl";
             TableCell c2 = new TableCell();
             c2.Controls.Add(ddl);
             r.Cells.Add(c2);
             Table1.Rows.Add(r);
            }
 }

 public void Button2_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)

 {

         foreach (TableRow tr in Table1.Controls)
         {
             foreach (TableCell tc in tr.Controls)
             {
                 if (tc.Controls[2] is DropDownList)
                {
                 Response.Write(((DropDownList)tc.Controls[2]).SelectedItem.Text+" ");
                }
             }
             Response.Write("<br/>");
         }
```

Problem is with the Selection of dropdownlist items.I could not print the corresponding selected item values.could anyone help?

Comment: What is happening? Did you get an exception or you are not able to find the dropdownlist or your dropdownlist is empty?

Answer (score 0):

Check tc.Controls[2] when you are in the last nested foreach. Is it possible that your dropdown list is something other than the third control?

I don't see any reason that would force it to be the third control in that Cell.

You would probably be better off doing something like this:

```
if(tc.FindControl("ddl") != null)
{
   Response.Write(((DropDownList)tc.FindControl("ddl")).SelectedItem.Text+" ");
}
```

instead of:

```
 if (tc.Controls[2] is DropDownList)
 {
    Response.Write(((DropDownList)tc.Controls[0]).SelectedItem.Text+" ");
 }
```

Comment: i edited the control part.but the problem is not with that i guess.still iam facing the same problem.

Comment: still its not printing the selected values.though i tried ur code.

Comment: Is it even getting to that if statement?

Comment: Its not giving any error.But just not giving any results after ther button2 click.